# Cómo conectar Mysql Workbench con un proyecto en android studio

Tags: sql, android-studio, mysql-workbench

necesito alguna guia o paso a paso de como puedo conectar una base de datos en mysql workbench a un proyecto en android studio utilizando el lenguaje Java, quiero recalcar que ya lo hice en intelijjie idea con java y si pude conectarla, pero cuando intento conectarla en android studio me da una serie de errores y no me logro hacer la conexión correctamente

Agradecería una explicación no importa que sea larga, la idea es aprender y entender de la mejor manera

sin más muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create una clase que extienda de SQLiteOpenHelper
2. Implementa todos los métodos necesarios
3. Create métodos que necesites como para insertar, eliminar, etc

public class DBAccess extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
//Database name
private static final String DB_NAME = "db_dam";

//Table name
private static final String DB_TABLE_NAME = "db_ciudades";

//Database version must be >= 1
private static final int DB_VERSION = 3;

//Columns
private static final String CITY_COLUMN = "cityName";
private static final String POBLATION_COLUMN = "poblation";
private static final String SURFACE_COLUMN = "surface";

//Context
private Context mContext;

public DBAccess(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);

    mContext = context;

}

//Todo 2. Sobrecargamos onCreate, encargado de crear las tablas asociadas a la base de datos.
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

    String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLE_NAME + "("
            + CITY_COLUMN + " TEXT,"
            + POBLATION_COLUMN + " INTEGER,"
            + SURFACE_COLUMN + " NUMERIC)";

    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log("onUpadre");
    Log("oldversion -> "+oldVersion);
    switch(oldVersion){
        case 1:
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + DB_TABLE_NAME  +" ADD COLUMN " + POBLATION_COLUMN +" INTEGER");
            Log.i("DB", "BBDD Actualizada a la versión 2");
        case 2:
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + DB_TABLE_NAME  +" ADD COLUMN " + SURFACE_COLUMN +" FLOAT");
            Log.i("DB", "BBDD Actualizada a la versión 3");
    }
}


public void getVersionDB(){
    Log(Integer.toString(this.getReadableDatabase().getVersion()));
}

//Metodo insertar
public long insert(String city, int poblation, float superficie){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    long result = -1;

    // Contenedor clave,valor -> columna, valor de entrada registro
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(CITY_COLUMN, city);
    values.put(POBLATION_COLUMN, poblation);
    values.put(SURFACE_COLUMN, superficie);

    result = db.insert(DB_TABLE_NAME,null,values);

    //Se cierra la conexión de la base de datos
    db.close();

    return result;

}
//Método eliminar
public void delete(String city){
    //Permiso de escritura en la base de datos
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    //Eliminamos
    db.delete(DB_TABLE_NAME, "cityName=?", new String[]{city});
    //Se cierra la conexión de la base de datos
    db.close();
}
//Metodo actualizar
public void update(String city, int poblation, float superficie){
    //Permiso de escritura en la base de datos
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    //ContentValues para actualizar los datos
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(POBLATION_COLUMN, poblation);
    values.put(SURFACE_COLUMN, superficie);
    //Actualizamos
    //Nombre tabla, valores nuevos
    db.update(DB_TABLE_NAME, values, "cityName=?",new String[]{city});
    //Se cierra la conexión de la base de datos
    db.close();
}
//Para cargar todas las ciudades de la base de datos
public ArrayList<Ciudad> getAllCities(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ArrayList<Ciudad> resultCities = new ArrayList<>();

    String[] cols = new String[]{ CITY_COLUMN, POBLATION_COLUMN, SURFACE_COLUMN};

    //String selection = "city=? AND poblation>?"; // -> el caracter interrogación será sustituido por los valores del array 'args' en orden de aparición
    //String[] args = new String[]{"jerez", "100"};

    //Un cursor es un tipo de dato que se mueve entre los registros devueltos por una consulta de una base de datos.
    Cursor c = db.query(DB_TABLE_NAME,cols,null,null,null,null,null);

    //Todo 6.1. Movemos el iterador al primer elemento (si existe devuelve true sino false)
    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            //
            String nombreCiudad = c.getString(0);
            int poblacion = c.getInt(1);
            float superficie = c.getFloat(2);
            Ciudad ciudad = new Ciudad(nombreCiudad, poblacion, superficie);
            resultCities.add(ciudad);
        }while(c.moveToNext());
    }

    return resultCities;
}
public void Log(String msg){
    Log.d("DB", msg);
}
```

}

Si lo que querías era utilizar una base de datos del pc, no es posible (no tiene sentido que quieras acceder a una base de datos del pc desde un dispositivo móvil), si esa base de datos ya estaba creada en tu dispositivo móvil, lo único que tienes que hacer es reemplazar Database Name y Table Name, por los nombres que tuviese.

[Documentación oficial](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper)

Un saludo, espero que te sea útil.